# Big-O of the following code snippets?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Please help, I am not sure if my reasoning for Big-O is correct in the following examples. can someone please correct any errors in thinking here. Not sure about how the 'i' incrementing variable effects the user-inputted data 'n' in these cases. And generally just not sure if I am understanding big-O correctly or not.
Thank you

Example1:

```
for (i = 1; i < (n*n+3*n+17) / 4 ; i = i+1) // 1/4*(n^2+3n+17) since 1/4n^2 dominates it's O(n^2), curious how the i = i + 1 effects things, please help 
System.out.println("Sunshine"); // negligible time O(1) 
// Total = O(n^2) + O(1) = O(n^2)
```

Example2:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // O(n) here
if ( i % 2 == 0) // not sure here
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) // not sure
System.out.print("Bacon"); // negligible time O(1)
else
for (j = 0; j < n * n; j++) // not sure
System.out.println("Ocean"); // negligible time O(1)
// Total = ?
```

Example3:

```
 for (i = 1; i <= 10000 * n: i = i*2) // 1000*n so O(n) how does i = i * 2 effect things, please help
    x = x + 1; // negligible time O(1)
    // Total = O(n) + O(1) = O(n)
```

Example4:

```
for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++) // O(n)
for (j = 1; j <= n*3; j++) // n*3 so O(3n) but, since nested it's O(3n^2)
System.out.println("Apple"); // negligible time O(1)
// Total = O(n) + O(3n^2) = O(n^2)
```

Example5:

```
for (i = 1; i < n*n*n; i = i*n) // n*n*n = O(n^3) not sure how i = i * n effects things, please help.
    System.out.println("Banana"); // negligible time O(1)
// Total = O(n^3) + O(1) = O(n^3)
```

Comment: First one is O(n^2) *multiplied by* O(1). Same result though.

Comment: The analysis on most of the examples is wrong, though in *some* cases the result is correct (5 is *very* incorrect.. Hint: It's O(1)).

Comment: Second one, outer loop is `O(n)`. Inside this, because of the if statement, half the time it is `O(n)` and the other half the time it is `O(n^2)`. Outer * inner = `O(n) * O(n^2)` = `O(n^3)`

Comment: @Michael is that how that works. We calculate the runtimes of each line them multiply them at the end for their total?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please explain more, I want to understand what I am doing wrong in this analysis.

Comment: @yre Think, how many times the "Banana" will get printed for n=2? For n=5? For n = 1000? Try to run it, if you have trouble.

Comment: @yre If they are nested loops, yes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it will get printing from the range starting at i = 1 to the terminating point of n^3 and upon each iteration that i' incrementing variable get's multiplied by n. So doesn't it depend on what the user defined 'n' to be? If 'n' were 3 then it would be 3*3*3=27 so it would run from 1 to 27. I am rather confused.

Comment: @Michael only for nested loops? what about while and do-while loops? and if-statements?

Comment: Look at how the loop counter is updated. Which values `i` will take? Again, write it and run with a debugger for further understanding.

Comment: @yre Any nested looping, regardless of the type of loop.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, is loops the only possible thing that could cause a greater than 'n' type scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Example 5 is O(1)

`n^3 = ((((1) * n) * n) * n)` - it takes:

- 4 steps for i=1 to reach i=n^3 in value for n > 1,
- 1 step for n = 1,
- 0 steps for n < 0